# Regex String Within Negative Lookahead being selected

Tags: regex

So i am trying to write something that will select the colon and number in this situation... ie ":1"

```
"phoneNumber":1111111111
```

but not in a situation where the colon followed by a digit is between a pair of quotes... ie not match ':0' and ':2'

```
"lastLogon":"2019-04-17 14:08:25.732576"
```

I have this expression which selects everything in quote pairs.

```
((?=["]).+?(?=["])")
```

Which I tried to do the following with...

```
:\s?([-\d])(?!((?=["]).+?(?=["])"))
```

But this selects both of the occurrences above. Does anyone have a workaround, I think I might be misunderstanding how negative look-ahead works.

Thanks!

Edit:
Added info on what strings I wanted to match.

Comment: A) There is no negative lookahead in your regex, so why are you asking about negative lookahead not working? B) There are multiple colons and numbers in the sample input. Exactly *which* "colon and number" do you want to match?

Comment: @anubhava sorry i had the order swapped that was my mistake.

Comment: @Bohemian i wish to match ` :1 ` in the "phoneNumber":1111111111 string and not the `:0` or `:2` in the "lastLogon":"2019-04-17 14:08:25.732576" string

Comment: Well, you might as well use [`":(\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/Z5z4k0/2).

Comment: @MuamerBektić: You can use: `(?<=":)\d+`

Comment: I can't believe I missed such an obvious and simple solution. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Just match a colon followed by 3 or more digits:

```
:\d{3,}
```